# debug the function which calculates total time between two dates subtract the weekend

Tags: sql, t-sql, time

The below function calculates total time between two dates with subtracting the weekend, it works fine when two dates differ more than a a day, but within a day the results come with nagative, i dont really understand, anyone could fix it?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Gettotalhours]
(
    @startdate datetime2,@enddate datetime2 
)
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN

declare @dateweekends int
declare @totaltime bigint


Set @Dateweekends = 
  (DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
   +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate)   = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

set @totaltime= DATEDIFF(second,@StartDate,@EndDate)-@dateweekends*24*60*60

return @totaltime

END
```

Comment: Do you have an example? It seems to work for me (apart from returning seconds instead of hours). I tried SELECT dbo.Gettotalhours( '2013-01-01 05:00:00', '2013-01-01 05:00:01') and it returned 1

Comment: Days aren't always 24 hours long, if those date/time values have DST-enabled timezones attached.  What is this being used for - you might want to define a calendar file (including weekends and other holidays), and then a simple `COUNT(*)` would suffice (with appropriate filters).  You also seem to be missing conditions (eg. like if `@StartDate` is Saturday), and your code isn't multi-language safe.

Comment: @keith bloom  yes, i used the SELECT dbo.Gettotalhours('2012-01-01 22:09:45.000','2012-01-01 22:09:50.000'), the result is -86395

Comment: @clockwork-muse how can i define a calendar file? if in that case,how can i calculate this?

Comment: I think @Clockwork-Muse is referring to a [calendar *table*](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html), which has many uses.

Comment: @Pondlife - Yes, thanks, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT dbo.Gettotalhours('2012-01-01 22:09:45.000','2012-01-01 22:09:50.000')** does not working in your case because **2012-01-01** - Sunday so you do not need to count @Dateweekends at all if both arguments presents one day:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Gettotalhours]
(
    @startdate datetime2,@enddate datetime2 
)
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN

declare @dateweekends int
declare @totaltime bigint


Set @Dateweekends = 
  (DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
   +(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, @EndDate) > 1 AND DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   +(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, @EndDate) > 1 AND DATENAME(dw, @EndDate)   = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

set @totaltime= DATEDIFF(second,@StartDate,@EndDate)-@dateweekends*24*60*60

return @totaltime

END

GO
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1b148/1/0)

and you can debug your function with the set of test cases like this:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT 2 [sec] UNION ALL
    SELECT 20 UNION ALL
    SELECT 200 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2000 UNION ALL
    SELECT 20000 UNION ALL
    SELECT 200000),

[source] AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(second, -t.[sec], GETDATE()) [from], GETDATE() [to]
    FROM t)

SELECT *, [dbo].[Gettotalhours]([from], [to]) [result] from [source]
```

Comment: yeah, i found out, and i add a if condifition, if that day is sunday or saturday, then i set Dateweekends 0, below is the new one, it works with me, welcome to correct me:

Comment: i cant answer my questions.. sucks

Answer (score 0):

I change my function a little bit, it works for me, could you guys take a look, if it correct now?

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Gettotalhours]
(
    @startdate datetime2,@enddate datetime2 
)
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN

declare @dateweekends int
declare @totaltime bigint

if DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) in ('Sunday','Saturday') 
set @dateweekends=0
else 
Set @Dateweekends = 
  (DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
   +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate)   = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

set @totaltime= DATEDIFF(second,@StartDate,@EndDate)-@dateweekends*24*60*60

return @totaltime

END